# How to make Pop Art Photo Filter on Image

Tags: java, android

I want to make A Filter which called Pop Art Filter

[image: Pop Art Filter]

I am trying this solution

```
  public static Bitmap setPopArtGradientFromBitmap(Context context, Bitmap bmp) {
            int[] co = new int[]{Color.parseColor("#FFD900"),Color.parseColor("#FF5300"),Color.parseColor("#FF0D00"),Color.parseColor("#AD009F"),Color.parseColor("#1924B1")};
            float[] coP = new float[]{0.2f,0.4f,0.6f,0.8f,1.0f};

            Bitmap bitmap = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

            /* Create your gradient. */
            LinearGradient grad = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, canvas.getHeight(), co, coP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

            /* Draw your gradient to the top of your bitmap. */
            Paint p = new Paint();
            p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            p.setAlpha(110);
            p.setShader(grad);
            canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), p);

            return bitmap;
        }
```

And the result  I am getting..

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for here - a tutorial? A path forward?

Comment: Sorry Tutorial>

Comment: Reminder, tutorials are off-topic for StackOverflow. You are trying to make any picture into hand crafted art. This is an image processing problem. You have to be able to identify features like face, hair line, body outline, dress, eyes, lips and even ignore the background. Some of these problems are harder than others. A few courses in image processing and looking at OpenCV would be a start in order to understand the complexity of the task. Machine learning may be a different path, the closest may be [Deep Dream Generator](https://deepdreamgenerator.com) which is server based. Good luck.